# Curl giving error 411 when calling Azure DevOps API

Tags: curl, azure-devops, python-requests, http-post

I have tried various values for the `Content-Length`, Tried removing it altogether, setting it at 0, however, I still end up with the same message, not really sure what is causing this. The token is a `base64` encoded with `ASCII` charset. Not sure if that is relevant.

```
curl -s -X POST https://dev.azure.com/xxx-Updates/_apis/hooks/subscriptions?api-version=5.0 \
             -H 'Accept: application/json' \
             -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
             -H 'Authorization: Basic WJxcnV2bXRwZWZyY2d6dmJ2NDR3M3F3azVkaHVkdG01dmE1a2pvemprcDM2Ymc1eWptYQ==' \ 
             -d '{"publisherId": "tfs", "eventType": "workitem.created","scope": "all", "resource": {"id": 5, "rev": 1, "fields": {"System.AreaPath": "Any","System.WorkItemType": "Feature", "System.State": "New"},"url": ""},"resourceVersion": "1.0"}'
```

> Error:-
>
> ---
>
> HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a
> content length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS are you using? Windows or Linux?

According to my test, I can reproduce the issue on Windows OS with the same format settings.

[image]

However, it works by replacing single quotes with double quotes:

```
curl -s -X POST -L https://dev.azure.com/xxx/_apis/hooks/subscriptions?api-version=6.0 -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic OnUzcHBuZjUzdnFid3l3RyZ3FvYXRmeDJ3Z3JtNDN6dW10ZmJpd3FtZXE=" -d '{"consumerActionId":"httpRequest","consumerId":"webHooks","consumerInputs":{"url":"https://requestbin.com/r/envu0xpxxxx"},"eventType":"workitem.created","publisherId":"tfs","publisherInputs":{"areaPath":"","workItemType":"Feature","projectId":"757d8384-e2a3-41a9-bc07-55fa40adf692"},"resourceVersion":"1.0","scope":1}'
```

You can have a try for that.

Besides, you can also try to run the same curl command from [reqbin](https://reqbin.com/req/c-d2nzjn3z/curl-post-body). If it works, then there should be something wrong with your local environment.
[image]